# the meaning of "the thunder of mortars"

Tags: meaning, metaphors

> When the German army rumbles into town, Provost shows Séraphine scraping away at her canvas, her hymns replaced by **the thunder of mortars** while Uhde, the "dirty German", is forced to flee.

[Source](http://www.theguardian.com/film/2009/nov/29/seraphine-review).

Just one question regarding the review of the French movie Séraphine. I catched myself by hesitating the term "the thunder of mortars". I dont't know if it is meant literally or in some metaphorical way. Yesterday I watched this movie so I know that a trademark of the protagonist was her naive spiritual faith in St Mary the Virgin and angels which was expressed by her declaiming "the hymns". Firstly I thought that "the thunder of mortars" is some kind of the opposite of the hymns, e.i. some sort of swearing. But she did  not behave in such a way as I can remember. The second meaning that occured to me is that she changed her painting technique and material but this is strange too and I didn't notice this in the movie. So what is your opinion?

Comment: Probably "the thunder of mortars" drowns her hymns so that "the funder of mortars" is in the foreground (there's war going on) and her hymns are in the background. This is from the standpoint of the viewer. Had it been a peaceful time, the viewer of the movie would've "heard her hymns", but now that it's war he hears the rumble of tanks, the thunder of mortars. Maybe not literally, but they are "more powerful" and more salient. "[Beat, beat, drums! Blow, bugles, blow](http://www.poetryfoundation.org/poem/174737)", etc.

Comment: Yes, I mistook the perspective. And moreover, I overlooked that the mortar is in English a weapon too… Thank you for your clarification.

Comment: I'm closevoting for lack of prior research, since it seems the only reason OP had trouble understanding the usage is because he hadn't looked up the [**mortar = cannon**](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/mortar) definition.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously you haven't looked up the noun mortar in the dictionary. Whenever you feel that the supposed meaning of a word makes no sense it is a hint that you should check the word in a dictionary.

"mortar" has three separate meanings: 1 a bricklayer uses mortar when he sets up a wall - 2 a heavy gun/cannon - 3 a heavy bowl for crushing seeds and grains. And only meaning 2 makes sense in your text.

Actually we have not one noun with three meanings, but three nouns with different origin. Etymonline has it right when it lists mortar 1, mortar 2 and mortar 3.
http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=Mortar

Comment: To be fair, [artists can use mortars](http://www.dickblick.com/products/pebeo-mortars/), too. And since Séraphine is an artist who is scraping away at a canvas, I can see how this might throw a learner off track. Also, it's not just bricklayers who use mortars in sense 1: _In this art form [mosaic], small units of various colored materials, such as glass or ceramic, are arranged into a design and set in a mortar_ (quoted from _The Painter's Handbook: A Complete Reference_, by M.Gottsegen, 2006). "Mortar" can be used to describe [paint](http://journal.chemistrycentral.com/content/9/1/23), too.

Comment: [Another interesting usage of the word "mortar"](http://www.stucco-as-art.com/aboutstucco.php).